# Make Hibernate use a different List wrapper than PersistentBag

Tags: java, hibernate, kotlin

The Problem with `PersistentBag` is that it violates the Collections API `equals()` contract, which breaks unit test assertions via AssertJ's `containsExactlyInAnyOrder()`. Hibernate also has different wrapper implementations such as `PersistentList`, is there a way to force Hibernate (version 5.6.7) to use those instead of `PersistentBag`?

```
@Entity
data class AnalysisType(
    @Id
    name: String,

    @Column(name = "reference_type")
    @OneToMany(fetch = LAZY, cascade = [])
    val referenceTypes: List<ReferenceType>
)

@Entity
data class ReferenceType(
    @Id
    val id: Long,

    @Column
    val name: String
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there's something wrong with the unit tests. Comparing two collections using an equals doesn't seem the right approach. In particular, when using unordered lists, elements might not always be in the same order.

You also need to make sure that you've implemented the correct hashcode/equals for the entities.
In java, for ReferenceType, it should look like:

```
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if ( this == o ) {
                return true;
            }
            if ( !( o instanceof ReferenceType ) ) {
                return false;
            }
            ReferenceType rt = (ReferenceType) o;
            return Objects.equals( name, rt.name );
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash( name );
        }
```

That said, if you want to have a PersistentList, the mapping needs to reflect an ordered list. You can achieve this using `@OrderColumn`:

```
@Entity(name = "Person")
public static class Person {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @OrderColumn
    private List<Phone> phones = new ArrayList<>();

    //Getters and setters are omitted for brevity

}
```

You can find more in the Hibernate ORM documentation in the [section about collections of entities](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.6/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#collections-entity).

Comment: I set `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jpa.compliance.list: true` in application.yml but this didn't work.

Comment: I added `@OrderBy("name ASC")` to the collection definition, unfortunately that didn't work either

Comment: Sorry, it was `@OrderColumn` not `@OrderBy`.

Comment: It seems I was wrong about the property, I've removed that part from the answer

Comment: Have you implemented hashcode/equals for the entities?

Comment: I can't make it refer to ReferenceType.name, it always points to the mapping table when I define it as `@OrderColumn(name="name")` on the collection property

Comment: I'm using Kotlin data classes, they implement sensible hashCode() and equals() methods automatically

Comment: Its strange, debugging `MutableJpaComplianceImpl` it sets `jpa.compliance.list: true` but the collections still are Bags... need to investigate more

Comment: so it seems `JpaCompliance.isJpaListComplianceEnabled()` isn't used anywhere, unlike `isJpaClosedComplianceEnabled()` - this looks like a bug to me

Comment: OrderColumn doesn't work like that. `OrderColumn` will create an additional column on the schema to keep track of the order of the entities in the list. I think you are looking in the wrong place though. Adding hascode/equals to your entity should solve all the issue you are having

Comment: Kotlin data classes auto-generate hashCode() and equals(), this is not the issue. I understand `OrderColumn` requires schema changes, this is unfortunate and I wanted to avoid that. Maybe my last hope though.

Comment: I've created a testcase to show you that everything works with AssertJ and Java (if hashcode and equals are correct): https://github.com/DavideD/hibernate-test-case-templates/blob/88a82b90cf7e06ee4e10f97cf760262ac71a60fe/orm/hibernate-orm-5/src/test/java/org/hibernate/bugs/ORMUnitTestCase.java

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, though. If you create a test case I will have a look

Comment: thanks for taking the time, much appreciated - I tried the the `@OrderColumn` approach, collection is now a `PersistentList` and the test passes

Comment: this is the bug ticket btw: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-15287

Comment: I still think that there is something wrong with the tests. They should not be affected by the underlying implementation of the List. But you do you.

Comment: you are correct for 1st level lists - in that case the `containsExactlyInAnyOrder()` examines the individual list elements of the method arguments on its own, but I have lists nested deeper down the object graph and there it uses `equals()`

Comment: It seems to me that `containsExactlyInAnyOrder` is not the right method to use for your assertions in this case. I wouldn't change the schema of the db because it's not possible to use a specific method in AssertJ. Also, using OrderColumn can lead to performance issues if you need to update the association often because the indexes need to be updated accordingly. Are you also sure you need to have a deep equals for your tests? Usually with Hibernate one doesn't include the associations in the equals/hascode

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `containsExactlyInAnyOrder` from assertj the order of the elements does not matter. You can check for duplicates. If the `PersistentBag`  contains the same element twice you should use `containsOnly` which does not care about the order and is ignoring duplicates. The `equals` method on the `PersistentBag` should not matter too because the `contains...` assertions in assertj are comparing element by element for the collections.

It looks like they may be sth wrong in your tests. Can you post assertj message?

Comment: you are correct about the immediate arguments to `containsExactlyInAnyOrder`, but in my case I have nested collections which are ultimately compared using the  `org.assertj.core.internal.StandardComparisonStrategy#areEqual`method, which ends up calling `equals()`, so it really is `PersistentBag`'s fault